# Calculating date intervals between two dates as i have the date in string. How could i do this..?

Tags: android

Friends,

I was intended to know how to implement the date and time functions for android and java.

I'm developing an application which shows the posted date of images. I'm showing that date in a list view. For example. I'm showing something like // posted on : 20/3/2012. Instead of it, i want to calculate the time interval betweeen two date and the date i have in type string. Besides, i want to calculate seconds, minutes, hours too. How can i do this..?

Regards,
VELU

> Blockquote

After some googling i have got this way to do so. Finally it works.

> Blockquote

```
           SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date endDate = null;
    try {
        endDate = formatter.parse(tochangeDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date startDate = null;

    String curentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    try {
        startDate = formatter.parse(curentDateandTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }

    long diff = (startDate.getTime()) - (endDate.getTime());

    int numOfDays = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    int hours = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minutes = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60));
    int seconds = (int) (diff / (1000));
```

This is what i have done and it works charm

Comment: String dateString = mCreatedDateinfo; 
       
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd"); 
    Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString); 
  
     long diff = convertedDate.getTime() – startDate.getTime();//in Milli seconds  
      int numOfDays = diff/(1000*60*60*24);  
  
  Where createddateinfo is past date

Comment: Please edit your post and add the above code. If you have nicely formatted questions, and show what you've tried, we love to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written this quickly in a long winded way because I already had the library procedures to hand.

```
package com.me.mytime;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyTimeActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyTimeActivity";

    //Activity
    private Context context;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.context = this;

        Calendar c1 = stringToCalendar("2012-03-20");
        Calendar c2 = stringToCalendar("2012-03-26");
        String elapsedDaysText = getElapsedDaysText(c1, c2);
    }

    public static Calendar stringToCalendar(String dateString)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        try
        {
            date = formatter.parse(dateString);
            cal.setTime(date);
        }
        catch(ParseException e)
        {
            cal = null;
        }
        return cal;
    }   

    public String getElapsedDaysText(Calendar c1, Calendar c2)
    {
        long milliSeconds1 = c1.getTimeInMillis();
        long milliSeconds2 = c2.getTimeInMillis();
        long periodSeconds = (milliSeconds2 - milliSeconds1) / 1000;
        long elapsedDays = periodSeconds / 60 / 60 / 24;
        String elapsedDaysText = String.format("%d days ago", elapsedDays);
        return elapsedDaysText;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a method to convert the 20/3/2012 string into a pastDate Calendar object. Then use Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); to get the current time. Then build another method to work out the number of days between today and pastDate. Finally, to make it nicer, an if statement that handles if within the last day (e.g. "within last X hours") or older (e.g. as you requested: "X days ago").